# How to make a vertical line only between two points?

Tags: jsxgraph

I want a vertical line only between two points. Currently, I am doing this:

```
board.create('line',[[2, 4],[2, 6]]);
```

This draws an infinite vertical line. How would I just get a line between the two points? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You have to make it a 'segment' instead of a 'line.'